# Got exception in file picker c# and XAML if choose nothing?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have problem with my App i made choose button to select file from PC but i got exception if i didn't choose any files 
hope anyone can help 
thanks [image]

Edit: Code with Try/Catch blocks

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4"); 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma"); 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3"); 
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync(); 
var stream = (dynamic)null; 
try { 
      stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(music)); // optional to back to choose page 
 }
```

Comment: Post the actual code and error message in text, it is unclear what the text says in the picture. Judging by your title, you know there is a possibility that you won't select anything so you should add some error handling

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MadeYourDay.Windows.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this what exception says and i had use (try and catch) but fail

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    var stream;
    StorageFile file;
    try{
        file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAcessMode.Read);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //log or something
    }
    //the rest of the code
```

Comment: got the same exception

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: maybe you could try catch {} instead of using a parameter. Or maybe you could add file variable on the try block, or even add a finally block after the catch block. can you show me how are you using the try/catch?

Comment: openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            var stream = (dynamic)null;

            try
            {
               
                stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(music)); // optional to back to choose page 
            }

Comment: music is other xaml page i just redirect to it

Comment: Please try to put StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();  inside the try block. this is really wierd

Comment: i solved it already by another way  if (null != file)
            {
                stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                media.SetSource(stream, file.Path);



            } thank you all for your efforts

Comment: glad you've fixed it

Comment: i just need other help from you if you don't mind i want to know how to make the same code but in windows phone 8.1 i try to make it 4 days ago but it fail as ( openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync() ) is not for windows phone hope you can help me with it @Artur Peniche

Comment: well mate i am not into windows phone but with a quick search i've found something similar with what you're facing [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357363/openfilepicker-not-working-on-windows-phone-8-specified-method-is-not-supported

Comment: i had other problem just found ... how i can keep the music file playing even i had move to other page ... i found that if i move to another page the music stop @ArturPeniche

Comment: since i don't have your code on sight https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/241ba3b4-3e2a-4f9b-a704-87c7b1be7988/how-to-continue-playing-media-after-navigating-to-other-pages-in-app?forum=winappswithcsharp